# How do I get MercurialEclipse and Bitbucket to talk to each other?

Tags: eclipse, mercurial, bitbucket

I'm an Eclipse user, but I'm a newbie to Mercurial and to Bitbucket. I think I understand the command-line hg commands. I can create repositories, clone, push, pull, update, that stuff.

If I have a project in Eclipse, I can create a local repository for it. I can't figure out how to clone this repository up to Bitbucket.

If I have a project in Eclipse, I can create a remote repository on Bitbucket. Then I don't have a local repository, so I can't use any of the Team... commands, and can't do anything.

If I have a repository on Bitbucket, I can't get to it, because I don't have a local repository, so again I can't do anything.

If I create separate repositories locally and on Bitbucket, then I have two different repositories, and I don't know enough Mercurial to merge(?) different repositories.

There *must* be some blindingly obvious to get a project off the ground, but I'm blind to it. I can do this just fine from the command line, but MercurialEclipse is defeating me. No luck so far with Google and assorted documentation...

Help?

Answer (score 21):

Doing it **using Eclise "Team" UI**:

- Create a project in Eclipse and `"share"` it using Mercurial repository type. That will create local repository (by default in the same location where your project is).
- Create project repository on BitBucket.
- Use `"Team">"Push"` to push local changes to your remote BitBucket repo. First time it will ask you to enter the repository URL, user name and password. All this information is available on your Bitbucket web UI.

Don't forget that you have to do 2 stage commits after that. Commit in Eclipse UI will commit it in your local repository. In your team perspective's Synchronize view you will see additional "Outgoing" and "Incoming" entries. Using right-click menu on them you will be able to push/pull your changes to/from your BitBucket repo.

Remote repo information can be managed in special "Mercurial Repositories" view.

More info can be found in the tutorials at http://ekkescorner.wordpress.com/blog-series/git-mercurial/

Comment: Thanks, that worked like a charm! I don't know the "synchronize" command yet, but now that I've gotten to Square One I think I can figure it out.

Answer (score 5):

Following the directions provided by bitbucket should be enough.

You can either **create a repository on bitbucket and clone it on your desktop**:

```
hg clone https://bitbucket.org/youraccount/yourproject
...
hg pull -u # to pull changes and update
hg push # to push changes to this repo
```

Or **use a local repository and push these changes to a newly created repository** on bitbucket:

```
cd /path/to/existing/hg/repo/
hg add [...]
hg commit 
hg push https://bitbucket.org/youraccount/yourproject
```

Basically, two repositories are "bound" by:

- a common changeset in their history
- the [paths] configuration in `/path/to/existing/hg/repo/.hg/hgrc`, that lists remote repositories you can read/push to.

Comment: Yes, doing it from the command line is easy. The question was about doing it in Eclipse, using the MercurialEclipse plugin.